# Error "Unexpected character encountered while parsing value"

Tags: c#, .net-core, httpclient

while I am trying to make a http request with httpClient I keep getting this error but I do not know why.

> Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: c. Path '',
>   line 0, position 0."]},"title":"One or more validation errors
>   occurred.","status":400,

here is my code, and I am using console application to make the request:

```
class Program {
    static void Main (string[] args) {
        Data _dt = new Data();
        _dt.IP = "192.156.25";
        _dt.LogText = "test from http";
        _dt.LogType = 1;
        _dt.StoreId = 14;
        _dt.StoreName = "testino";
        _dt.UserId = 2;
    NewAddStoreLog(_dt);
    }
    static void NewAddStoreLog (Data dt) {
        HttpClient http = new HttpClient ();

        var content = new StringContent (dt.ToString (), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        var result = http.PostAsync ("http://192.168.8.180:88/Logs/RecordLogs", content).Result;
        string strResult = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString (result.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync ().Result);
        System.Console.WriteLine(strResult);
    }
}
public class Data {
    public int StoreId { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string IP { get; set; }
    public int LogType { get; set; } //Enum
    public string LogText { get; set; }
    public string StoreName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Read the error message. It clearly tells why you get the error...

Comment: It looks like you are sending invalid json in the request. What is the value of `dt.ToString()`

Comment: Use `var content = new JsonContent (dt);` instead.

Comment: A task for you: Print the result `dt.ToString()` in a console window. This is the content you are trying to send as data type "application/json", so you should take a close and hard look at it when confronted with errors...

Comment: @JessedeWit what will that accomplish? I've never had a problem with `StringContent`.

Comment: @Crowcoder Well, you can use `StringContent` ofcourse, but if you do that, you'll have to serialize the object to json first. The ToString() probably does not return a json string, as you noted in your comment.

Comment: @JessedeWit I see, I looked to me like there was an attempt at json with `ToString()` because the error showed some json-ish content but we can only guess.

Comment: I should have serialized dt before sending it. thanks @elgonzo

Comment: @elgonzo `"]},"title":"` looks json-ish to me. If not, where would "title" come from? Is that a partial representation of what the server is expecting?

Comment: @Crowcoder, that is part of the servers response data structure (which itself is formatted/serialized as json) that is sent back to the client. Not related to the actual data causing the error. (The `]}` fragment just being a part of the response data structure not wholly shown here in the question)